# how to fix (scheduledDate): Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime' error in in flutter in 2023?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I was creating a zonedSchedule notification for a daily alarm. and whenever i passed the date dynamically it throws an error. `Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (scheduledDate): Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime'`. when i use manual duration time like `tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5))` it will automatically make an alarm for the whole scheduled date all at once. but when i use the dynamic it throws the above error.

```
 setNotification(
      {required DateTime time,
      required int id,
      required bool isAdhan,
      required String salat,
      required String adhan}) async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    Duration duration = time.difference(DateTime.now());

    // final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    // final location = await tz.getLocation("Africa/Addis_Ababa");
    // tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime.from(time, location);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        "$salat Prayer Time",
        "It's time for $salat Prayer, Pray at the time",
        // tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
        // scheduledDate.add(duration),
        tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(time.difference(DateTime.now())),

        NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(), "channelName",
                channelDescription: "Adhan For Prayer",
                playSound: isAdhan,
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                fullScreenIntent: true,
                sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(adhan))),
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        payload: "Prayer");
  }
```

how i'm initializing the schedule is

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i));
    ... other codes ...

    if(morning.isNow) {
      schedule.add(Reminder(
        id: 1+6 *i,
        time: alarmTime // alarmTime is of type DateTime? .
      ))
    }
    ... other plans

}
```

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i this your are trying to find the time difference of `time` from the argument with `current time` and added so the result must be in `DateTime` formate. may be u can convert the `DateTime` to `TZDateTime` it can work

```
tz.TZDateTime.from(dt, tz.local);
```

like below try and let me know

check for more [ref](https://pub.dev/documentation/timezone/latest/timezone.standalone/TZDateTime-class.html)

```
tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add( tz.TZDateTime.from(time.difference(DateTime.now()), tz.local)),
```

Comment: it has an error `The argument type 'TZDateTime' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Duration'.`